# How to Normalize datetime

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, normalization

I have this function to put date and time in the same format `yyyy-mm-dd` `hh:mm`, When given entry data in  `yyyy/m/d` or `yyyy/mm/dd` and `h:m` or `hh:mm`, it returns
`undefined`, which isn't the expected result.

```js
 function normalizeDate(datetime) {
  date = datetime.match(/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/g);
  time = datetime.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}[a|p]/g);
  
  if(date && time){ // if both have a match
    date = date[0];
    time = time[0];
  
    if(time.match('a')) return new Date(date + " 07:00"); 
    else if(time.match('p')) {
      if(+(time.substr(0,2)) < 10) return new Date(date + " 15:00"); 
      else return new Date(date + " 23:00"); 
    }   
  }else{
    date = datetime.match(/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/g);
    time = datetime.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/g);
    if(date && time){ // if both have a match
      date = date[0];
      time = time[0];
        if(+(time.substr(0,2)) < 7) return new Date(date + " 7:00"); 
        if(+(time.substr(0,2)) > 22) return new Date(date + " 23:00"); 
        else return new Date(date + " 15:00"); 
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: You should declare variables with *let*, *var* or *const*. The *else* loop seems to replicate logic that has already been implemented above, so `if (date && time)` fails if both don't have a match in the else branch too.

Comment: BTW, `new Date('2020-07-17 23:00')` returns an invalid Date in Safari. You should manually parse the result, not rely on the built–in parser, especially for unsupported formats.